# Substitute or remove links from content

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

So I have some content with some `href` links the links look like so:

```
<p>Here you can find
    <a href="ssNODELINK/SurvivalStatistics">Survival stats </a>
    <a href="ssNODELINK/SmokingStatistics">Smoking stats </a>
    <a href="ssNODELINK/RisksAndCauses"> and Risks </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.something.ac.uk/"> Something </a>
of recent research</p>
```

And a few more

My desired result is to remove all `ssNODELINKs` that you see listed and keep other links. the result would look like:

Here you can find Survival stats Smoking stats and Risks of recent research [Something](http://www.somthingggggggggg.com)

I have tried the following lines of code to achieve this:

```
page_content.gsub!(/(<a href="ssNODELINK/a-zA-Z">)/, ''))
```

And

this only removes part of it

```
page_content.gsub!(/(<a href="ssNODELINK)/, ''))
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve my desired result?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _removing a link_? Would you like to just remove the hyperlink wrapper (`<a href="..."></a>`) or would you like to remove everything including the link text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML <<-eot
<p>Here you can find
    <a href="ssNODELINK/SurvivalStatistics">Survival stats </a>
    <a href="ssNODELINK/SmokingStatistics">Smoking stats </a>
    <a href="ssNODELINK/RisksAndCauses"> and Risks </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.something.ac.uk/"> Something </a>
of recent research</p>
eot

nodesets = doc.css('p > a')
nodesets.each do |nd|
  nd.unlink if nd['href'].include? 'ssNODELINK'
end

puts doc.to_html.gsub(/^\s*\n/, "") 
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>Here you can find
# >>     <a target="_blank" href="http://www.something.ac.uk/"> Something </a>
# >> of recent research</p></body></html>
```